# jQuery AJAX Calls - Is it possible to cancel unwanted calls?

Tags: php, jquery

I just wanted to ask. I have text input to allow users to type their city.

jQuery has a `keyup` event linked to this input and sent an AJAX call after each character change.

I find however many unrequired AJAX calls are sent as the person is typing and depending on the number of results this can slow down performance here.

Is there a way to cancel AJAX calls if a new call is made? Is there a better way to do this?

An example can be seen here: [www.datingjapan.co](http://www.datingjapan.co)

Comment: Adam, have you imposed a minimum character restriction before calling the function? I think the best practice is to not call something until you want to, as opposed to calling it 50 times and weeding out the 40 you don't want. Or impose a limit of responses on your return data?

Comment: usually you have 2 controls. One to only start doing ajax after so many characters  have been entered (3-4). The other is to send to ajax if nothing has been entered in half a second-one second or so. Otherwise it'll hit the database too much and could slow down user interaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `abort` method of the [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object returned by the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method (other AJAX methods like `get` and `post` return a `jqXHR` instance too):

```
var xhr = $.ajax(opts);
xhr.abort();
```

Note that the `jqXHR` object is effectively just an extension of `XMLHttpRequest`, and `XMLHttpRequest` itself also has an [`abort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) method.

Comment: ok so with jquery I can abort previous calls. Does this mean an abort is sent from the to the server and the operation is cancelled? If I'm sending multiple of the same post request would they all be cancelled or is there a way to identify the one to cancel?

Comment: @Adam - The `abort` is sent from the client to the server. Each `jqXHR` object represents one single request. If you call the `abort` method of a single instance of `jqXHR`, that single request is cancelled.